# Extracting python List

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which has strings in it like this

```
ID value
1  2
2  25,35
3  1,25,3,40
```

I would like to count the number of times each value occurs.
The values are strings not integers or floats

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, using string ascessor, `split`, `stack` and `value_counts`:

```
df.value.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
25    2
2     1
1     1
3     1
35    1
40    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: ha-ha, i had exactly the same solution :-)

Comment: I refrained from posting this answer although I had it almost 4 minutes ago... seeing the downvotes pile up on this question. I was afraid people were white knighting it.

Comment: What's that badge for the turnaround? "Reverseal" Oh forgot it.  20 upvotes. :)   Not enough of a Pandas audience these days.

Answer (score 0):

Pass all the values to a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like this:

```
counter = Counter()
for value in values:
     counter[value] += 1
```

Comment: @pythonninja: they often down-vote questions that show no evidence of prior effort from the original poster. Did you show your own code attempt in your question?

Comment: No I didnt know..I am new so from now on I will.